# How to make invisible a line in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I tried unsuccessfully to remove or to make invisible the line connecting the left `wall` to the first block `$m_1$`. How can I do this ? I think it's an easy thing, but I don't know exactly.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
   decorations.markings,
   decorations.pathmorphing,
   calc,
   patterns,
   positioning
}

\tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      },
     box/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}
    }

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm] {};
        \node (M1) [box, right=of wall.north] {$m_1$};
        \node (M2) [box,right=of M1,label=below:$f$] {$m_2$};

        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.north) -- (M1) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {};
        \draw (wall.20) -- (wall.20 -| M1.west) coordinate (d1);

        \draw [spring] (M1) -- (M2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {} ;
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M1.east) -- (d1 -| M2.west);

        \node (wall2) [ground, right=of M2, anchor=north,rotate=90,minimum width=2cm] {};
        \draw [spring] (M2) -- (wall2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M2.east) -- (d1 -| wall2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is:[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Replace `\draw` by `\path`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
   decorations.markings,
   decorations.pathmorphing,
   calc,
   patterns,
   positioning
}

\tikzset{
      spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
      blank/.style={draw=none,fill=none,pos=0.5},
      ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
      damper/.style={thick,
         decoration={markings, mark connection node=dmp,
           mark=at position 0.5 with
          {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
          }
          }, decorate
      },
     box/.style={draw,thick,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}
    }

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
        \node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm] {};
        \node (M1) [box, right=of wall.north] {$m_1$};
        \node (M2) [box,right=of M1,label=below:$f$] {$m_2$};

        \draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
        \draw [spring] (wall.north) -- (M1) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {};
        \path (wall.20) -- (wall.20 -| M1.west) coordinate (d1);

        \draw [spring] (M1) -- (M2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {} ;
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M1.east) -- (d1 -| M2.west);

        \node (wall2) [ground, right=of M2, anchor=north,rotate=90,minimum width=2cm] {};
        \draw [spring] (M2) -- (wall2) node[blank,above,yshift=1mm] {};
        \draw [damper] (d1-|M2.east) -- (d1 -| wall2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or `draw` it without color: `\draw[draw=none] ...`

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus Instead of editing in other user's suggestions without giving them credit, please ask them to post an answer themselves if you think having this as comment is not enough

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my apologies. It was far from my intention not to give credit to Ignasi. I was trying to be practical by summarizing Ignasi's suggestion at the beginning of your answer: more clarity and quick access for the person seeking an answer. Thanks for informing! I created an answer with further explanations and the due credit. :)  Be blessed.

Answer (score 4):

I want to expand on the comment of [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi).

You can also make any line invisible by adding the option

`draw=none`

to the tikz command that is drawing. This option has some **advantages** that I comment below.

In your case, you have to change the line

```
 \draw (wall.20) -- (wall.20 -| M1.west) coordinate (d1);
```

by

```
 \draw[draw=none] (wall.20) -- (wall.20 -| M1.west) coordinate (d1);
```

### Advantages

See TikZ Manual 3.1.5b Section 15.3 *Drawing a path*: "If the special color name none is given, this option causes drawing to be “switched off”. This is useful
if a style has previously switched on drawing and you locally wish to undo this effect."

As an example of usefulness, imagine you have a scope where all the node frames are set to be drawn (`every node/.style=draw`), but you want to make an exception (see node C)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[every node/.style=draw]
\path (0,0) node{A};
\path (0,1) node{B};
\path (1,0) node[draw=none]{C};
\path (1,1) node{D};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Note that in this particular case the solution of [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) cannot be used. ;)